# Переделать запрос на перечисление параметров

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT name FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT list_ims.id, list_ims.name 
 FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name 
 WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
   AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
   AND test_name.name LIKE "%IIH%мкА" 
   AND measuring.down_board >= -4 
   AND measuring.up_board <= 84
) AS Q1,
(SELECT DISTINCT list_ims.id 
 FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name 
 WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
   AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
   AND test_name.name LIKE "%IIL%мА" 
   AND measuring.down_board >= -3.35 
   AND measuring.up_board <= 4.35
) AS Q2,
(SELECT DISTINCT list_ims.id 
 FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name 
 WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
   AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
   AND test_name.name LIKE "%UOH%" 
   AND measuring.down_board >= -0.35000000000000003 
   AND measuring.up_board <= 7.35
) AS Q3,
(SELECT DISTINCT list_ims.id
 FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name 
 WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
   AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
   AND test_name.name LIKE "%UOL%" 
   AND measuring.down_board >= -0.1 
   AND measuring.up_board <= 2.1
) AS Q4 
WHERE Q1.id=Q2.id 
  AND Q1.id=Q3.id 
  AND Q1.id=Q4.id
```

Есть ли возможность переделать его в что-то вроде:

```
SELECT DISTINCT list_ims.id, list_ims.name 
FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name 
WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
  AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
  AND    (test_name.name, measuring.down_board, measuring.up_board) 
     IN ((набор параметров с LIKE и операторами сравнения 1),
         (набор параметров с LIKE и операторами сравнения 2),
         (набор параметров с LIKE и операторами сравнения 3),
         (набор параметров с LIKE и операторами сравнения 4))
```

Comment: гм... а что собсно мешает-то? просто надо дополнительно группировать по `list_ims.id, list_ims.name` (при этом DISTINCT есссно станет не нужен) и в HAVING проверить COUNT. Ну разве что с группой полей ТАК нельзя - придётся писАть наборы с отдельными полями. Хотя я бы затолкал набор условий во временную таблицу...

Comment: С другой стороны не факт, что это будет эффективно - особенно если таблицы пухлые.

Comment: @Akina просто это сейчас наборов параметров 4, в будущем пользователь может их сколько угодно, и на каждый нужно будет свой SELECT добавлять. И походу придется писать цикл какой-нибудь и обходить все выбранные параметры, чтобы корректно общий запрос составить.

Comment: Тогда тем более - складывайте наборы параметров фильтрации во временную таблицу, и добавьте в неё числовое поле, интерпретируемое как битовое (если таких наборов будет в пределах 63 штук, уложишься в стандартный тип). Тогда в HAVING OR-им это поле и сравниваем с требуемой маской вхождения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT list_ims.id, list_ims.name 
  FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name,
       (select "%IIH%мкА" as mask, -4 as down, 84 as up   UNION ALL
        select "%IIL%мА", -3.35, 4.35                     UNION ALL
        select "%UOH%", -0.35000000000000003, 7.35        UNION ALL
        select "%UOL%", -0.1, 2.1
       ) src
 WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
   AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
   AND test_name.name LIKE src.mask
   AND measuring.down_board >= src.down
   AND measuring.up_board <= src.up
 GROUP BY list_ims.id, list_ims.name
HAVING count(distinct src.mask)=4
```

Условие в count можно упростить, сведя к `count(1)`, в случае, если в исходных данных встречается гарантированно не более одной записи, подходящей под конкретную строку условий.